# Charm++ State_Space_searchengine Compiling error

Tags: charm++

I am trying to compile and run TSP problem in charm++ framework. The Code is mentioned in the State_Space_SearchEngine directory inside TSP_SE folder. I have compiled it as per the README file mentioned in the directory. As it says to run 'make OPTS=-O3' command in //tmp/libs/ck-libs/state_space_searchengine/ that I have done. And after doing this when I run the TSP_SE application using 'make OPTS=-O3' command I am getting these errors.

Please help me out.[Compilation Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59u7K.png)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error all you need to do is make the mainchare class (Main) inherit from CBase_Main in file main.C of the TSP_SE directory.

This fix has been incorporated into the mainline development version of Charm++ and will be a part of the Charm++ v6.8.0 release. Thanks for pointing it out.